# how to convert a chrome extension to firefox addon?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have written my first chrome extension.

Is there an easy way (using JS/HTML5/CSS) to convert that to Firefox ?

I don't really feel like learning XUL and new APIs

I found many sites that points to :
http://gallery.extensionfactory.com/labs/conversion/

But this service looks down.

Any clue ?

Comment: What does your addon do? There is the [tag:firefox-addon-sdk] which is designed for new people.

Comment: yes. It uses websockets

Comment: upload to github ill have to see what all is around it to tell you how to go about it. there isnt a tool to do the conversion for you.

Comment: https://github.com/yarekc/shoutbox

(I don't use github: I hope this is ok for you !)

Comment: Thanks thats good effort. So this looks real simple. You just have an html file called `shoutbox.html` and that is a chat client? So would you like to see if someone typed in `about:shoutbox` it should load your client?

Comment: the process is done in background.html 
background and shoutbox.html do communicate together

Comment: How do users open your chat page? edit: oic, it opens in a panel from the toolbar menu huh?

Comment: they click on the ... extension icon.
Maybe the simplest way would be to test install it and try it: you will understand at glance.

users are permenantly connected to chat. Once they click on extension button, the chat window opens in chrome popup

Comment: ok cool ill post something up for you to look at later. its pretty basic. just using `CustomizableUI.jsm` and `chrome` files for bootstrap style. Of if you want to do addon-sdk style then `require('panel')` and `self.data.url('your file')` files

Comment: one question: what if user has multiple windows open? will the content of the panel be new connection? or same connection?

Comment: same connection: you don't have to worry about it: it is automatically managed on server part.

Infact You can ONLY have in chrome 1 active-focused tab: you do connect to that focused tab. Any time you change tab, you disconnect from old one and connect to new one.

Comment: aw man thats a lot of uneeded overhead though. let me try to figure this out its on the tip of my fingers, i have use for a single resuable panel as well.

Comment: well . I don't think you can do that another way : you must be connected to get real time badge to know how many people are connected . Do you have a better idea ?

Comment: Ya the panel will be real time connected. And u can just do simple json request for badge :)\

Comment: that's the way it works... Anyway, what about my original request about adapting that to firefox ?

Comment: I've been busy i havent been able to write code for you yet. In the mean time though check out firefox addon sdk and panel: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Attaching_panels_to_buttons

Comment: ok im learning some awesome stuff! if you dont want this way go ahead with that sdk its like 10minutes with that. i dont know sdk otherwise i would help you. but with the cool way im learning we use the `SharedFrame.jsm` module real cool! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535915/reusable-panel-from-hiddendomwindow/26639726#26639726

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: here's a new tool to convert from chrome extension to firefox its called chrome tailor: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla-labs-jetpack/uMku5y1XzRM and here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla-labs-jetpack/CGIrbHg8mTM