# Reusable Panel from hiddenDOMWindow

Tags: firefox-addon

I have a CustomizableUI.jsm button i add to the toolbar. On click of this it opens a panel which has a chrome page loaded.

I want all windows to open this same panel. So my thought was to add the panel to `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow` and then open it anchored to the the CustomizableUI.jsm button.

However I'm having trouble adding the panel to the hidddenDOMWindow.

This code works fine from scratchpad if you make the first line be `var win = window`. But if you make it be `var win = Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow` it has trouble appending the panel to the popupset. So weird.

Code here is the appShell hidden window code. If you make it `var win= window` it works fine:

```
var win = window; //Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow;
var panel = win.document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul','panel');
var props = {
    type: 'arrow',
    style: 'width:300px;height:100px;'
}
for (var p in props) {
    panel.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
}

var popupset = win.document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul','popupset');
popupset.appendChild(panel);
win.document.documentElement.appendChild(popupset);

panel.addEventListener('popuphiding', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //panel.removeEventListener('popuphiding', arguments.callee, false); //if dont have this then cant do hidepopup after animation as hiding will be prevented
    panel.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
        panel.hidePopup(); //just hide it, if want this then comment out line 19 also uncomment line 16
        //panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel); //remove it from dom //if want this then comment out line 18
    }, false);
    panel.ownerDocument.getAnonymousNodes(panel)[0].setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate(0,-50px);opacity:0.9;transition: transform 0.2s ease-in, opacity 0.15s ease-in');
}, false);

panel.openPopup(window.document.documentElement, 'overlap', 100, 100);
```